# Sub-menu items in twig

Tags: 8, theming, navigation

How can I theme all the menu levels individually in menu.html.twig?

I need to give different markup to the 2nd (child) and 3rd (grandchild) level, and in the twig I only have parent and child.

```
  {% if item.below %}
    {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes.removeClass('nav'), menu_level + 1) }}
  {% endif %}
```

Whatever I put in this is duplicated for the child and grandchildren.

I thought that `menu_level + 2` might get it. What does `menu_level +` do?

---

**EDIT:
Thanks to Hudri's tip below I did the following** Thanks Hudri!

```
  {% if menu_level == 0 and item.is_expanded %}
    <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
    <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="dropdown-toggle nav__title" data-target="" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ item.title }} </a>
  {% elseif menu_level == 1 %}
    <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
    {{
      link(
        item.title,
        item.url,
        item.attributes.removeClass(item_classes),
        item.attributes.setAttribute('title', '')
      )
    }}
  {% elseif menu_level == 2 %}
    <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
    {{
      link(
        item.title,
        item.url,
        item.attributes
      )
    }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`menu_links` is a Twig macro, that is called recursively. That macro is located in `menu.html.twig`. In there you can do stuff based on current `menu_level`.

```
{% if menu_level == 0 %}
  <ul class="menu--main">
{% else %}
  <ul class="menu--sub">
{% endif %}
```

Notice that this macro is called recursivly, so if you are adding a classes like `{% set attributes = attributes.addClass('menu--level' ~ menu_level) %}`, this additional class is also stored and passed down recursivly!

Also take a look at `core/themes/classy/templates/navigation/menu.html.twig` to get an example of a full menu template file.

Comment: Thanks @Hudri! So there is no way to pick out different levels and apply specific theming?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, different for each level, but all has to be done in `menu.html.twig` - look at the example snippet I gave in the answer.

Comment: Recursively means that the same template file is called multiple times. But each time the `menu_level` variables is set to a new value. React on that variable to create depth specific design.

Answer (score 1):

Use macro instead, that's better for recursive twig

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Can you expand this answer a little to show how a Twig macro can be used for this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example code of macro.

````
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    {% else %}
      <ul class="menu sub-nav">
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {%
        set classes = [
          'menu-item',
          item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
          item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
        ]
      %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}```
````